What Does the "Arguments" Field in the Functions Tab of IDA Represent?
I want to efficiently find specific functions in IDA Pro by using the "Arguments" value in the Functions tab. However, for the following code examples, which were obtained from IDA  decompilation:
__int64 __fastcall sub_49FB60(__int64 a1)
{
  sub_484690(a1 + 208, 0LL);
  sub_484690(a1 + 112, 0LL);
  return sub_484690(a1 + 16, 0LL);
}

_QWORD *__fastcall sub_4A0050(_QWORD *a1, __int64 a2)
{
  sub_4A3CB0(a1);
  *a1 = off_979AD8;
  a1[13] = a2;
  return a1;
}

__int64 __fastcall sub_4D3D20(__int64 a1, __int64 a2, unsigned __int8 a3)
{
  __int64 v5; // rcx

  *(_QWORD *)a1 = a2;
  v5 = *(_QWORD *)(*(int *)(*(_QWORD *)a2 + 4LL) + a2 + 72);
  if ( v5 )
    (*(void (__fastcall **)(__int64))(*(_QWORD *)v5 + 8LL))(v5);
  *(_BYTE *)(a1 + 8) = sub_4D3BC0(*(_QWORD *)a1, a3);
  return a1;
}

All of these functions have an "Arguments" value of 00000010. Initially, I thought it might represent the sum of argument sizes, but the calculations do not match. What does the "Arguments" field actually represent?
【Functions Tap Image】
Additionally, what does the "Arguments" value represent for the code examples provided?
__int64 __fastcall sub_52AFD0(unsigned int **a1, unsinged int a2, __int64 a3)
{
    unsinged int v3;
    unsinged int v4;
    unsinged int v6;
    unsinged __int i;
    
    v6 =-1;
    for ( i = a2 / 8ui64; i; --i)
    {
      v3 = **a1 ^ v6;
      ++*a1;
      v4 = **a1;
      v6 = *(_DWORD *)(a3 + 4i64 * (v4 >> 24)));
    }
    return v6;
}


What does the assembly code look like? I would assume that the Arguments value is what's added to RSP on exit (not including the return address).

Please show the assembly for some of these functions, and also same function's stack layout (Edit->Functions->Stack variables).

Since it's my first time using Stack Overflow, I didn't realize that responses could be posted here. Sorry for the late reply.
I will provide the assembly code you requested.





It would be useful to add to the question what architecture this is.  x86_64 (aka amd64)?

Did you manually type the decompiled code snippets in the question?  I am skeptical that IDA would misspell unsigned as unsinged.

The value in the "Arguments" column seems to represent the space reserved for function arguments before the function stack frame (higher stack addresses). Therefore, it does not represent the total size of all function arguments, but only those passed through the stack. Thanks to Andrey Turkin for pointing this out in the comments below.
For example, disassembling /bin/awk on my x86-64 Linux system with IDA Free 8.4 I see the following function:
__int64 __fastcall sub_47EC80(
        __int64 a1,
        unsigned int *a2,
        int a3,
        unsigned int a4,
        unsigned int a5,
        int a6,
        unsigned int a7)
{
    // ...
}

Its "Arguments" column displays 00000004. If I look at the disassembly I can see the following:
.text:000000000047EC80 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:000000000047EC80
.text:000000000047EC80
.text:000000000047EC80 ; __int64 __fastcall sub_47EC80(__int64, unsigned int *, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int)
.text:000000000047EC80 sub_47EC80      proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_47F350+2F↓p
.text:000000000047EC80                                         ; sub_47F500+6C5↓p
.text:000000000047EC80
.text:000000000047EC80 var_D0          = dword ptr -0D0h
   ... a bunch more var_XX here ...
.text:000000000047EC80 var_54          = dword ptr -54h
.text:000000000047EC80 ptr             = qword ptr -50h
.text:000000000047EC80 var_40          = qword ptr -40h
.text:000000000047EC80 arg_0           = dword ptr  8 
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ arg passed through stack
.text:000000000047EC80
.text:000000000047EC80 ; __unwind {
.text:000000000047EC80                 push    r15
.text:000000000047EC82                 mov     r15, rdi
.text:000000000047EC85                 push    r14
.text:000000000047EC87                 push    r13
.text:000000000047EC89                 push    r12
   ...

Notice that the only variable allocated past the stack pointer (with a positive offset of 8) is arg_0. That corresponds to the a7 argument in the function signature. In this case the first 6 arguments are passed through the registers RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8 and R9. The 7th is passed on the stack.
In fact, if I take a look at the xrefs (press X on the function name) I can see this call:
.text:000000000047FBAD                 mov     [rsp+0E8h+var_E0], r10
.text:000000000047FBB2                 sub     rsp, 8
.text:000000000047FBB6                 mov     edx, [r15+4]
.text:000000000047FBBA                 mov     r9d, r13d
.text:000000000047FBBD                 push    9
.text:000000000047FBBF                 mov     r8d, ebp
.text:000000000047FBC2                 mov     rdi, r14
.text:000000000047FBC5                 call    sub_47EC80

As you can see the 7th argument is passed with push 9. Even though the instruction push 9 pushes a 8-byte value on the stack, the function then only seems to access the value using 4-byte (dword) dereference operations (or in any case treat it as a 4-byte value). That seems to be why the "Arguments" column shows 00000004.
Similarly, for this other function:
__int64 __fastcall sub_44DC90(
        __int64 a1,
        const char *a2,
        int a3,
        __int64 a4,
        __int64 a5,
        void (__fastcall *a6)(_QWORD, _QWORD, _QWORD, _QWORD),
        __int64 a7,
        __int64 a8,
        char a9)
{
    // ...
}

I can see the "Arguments" column shows 00000011 (17) because __int64 a7, __int64 a8 and char a9 are passed through the stack:
...
mov     rdi, 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
mov     [rsp+60h+var_48], rax
push    0
push    r12
push    rbp
call    r15
...


Looking into IDA Documentation
IDA has a pretty nice built-in documentation. If you position your cursor in the function window, and then press the F1 key, the documentation will pop up in a new window. Here's what it looks on my IDA Free 8.4.
Looking at the "Functions window" page in the documentation, the fields are:

function name
segment that contains the function
offset of the function within the segment
function length in bytes
size (in bytes) of local variables + saved registers
size (in bytes) of arguments passed to the function

The same documentation page is also available online here.
From the doc, it seems like the "Arguments" column should represent the "size of the arguments passed to the function". The Hex-Rays YouTube channel also has a video about the Functions window explaining things, and it also says that the "Arguments" column should represent the "size of arguments passed to the function".
These descriptions seem too generic and don't accurately describe the meaning of the column. It seems like the documentation page should be updated with clearer descriptions.
The same reasoning goes for the 2nd and 3rd columns (Segment and Start): the "Start" column definitely does not represent the offset within the ELF segment shown in the "Segment" column (even though it shows .text which is a section), but rather the absolute virtual address. It may be because as Ben Voigt suggests below the word "segment" in the documentation for the "Segment" column refers to binary (e.g. ELF) segments/sections, but for the "Start" column it may refer to architecture defined segments when the CPU uses a segmented memory model (e.g. segmented 16-bit x86 real mode). Confusing.

You are right about this field being the stack size of arguments area. IDA (x64) 7.7 shows exactly that. E.g. the field is unpopulated at all for 1-argument function in a Linux binary, but it is 8 for 1-argument function in a Windows binary (where the argument is still passed in an argument but then saved into shadow space). I think more specifically this field represents size of the stack area above return address, as shown in function stack window.

@AndreyTurkin now that makes a lot more sense. Even though there are weird cases this seems to be the correct definition. I will update my answer, thank you!

"is definitely not the "offset of the function within the segment", but the function's absolute virtual address... these are the same thing, unless using a segmented memory architecture (e.g. 16-bit x86).  "segment" != "section"

Could the "arguments" value have anything to do with the calling convention on caller-save and callee-save registers?  If a certain number of registers are available to the callee for use as scratch, even if no meaningful data is passed, they might still be treated as argument storage for the purposes of this calculation.

@BenVoigt You seem to be right that this seems to be the offset within the segment (as in the archtecture defined segment in a segmented memory model). That would make more sense. What is confusing though is that if you look at what IDA calls "segment" you can see that the "Segment" Column says .text... which is an ELF segment. So reading from the doc we see "segment that contains the function" immediately followed by "offset of the function within the segment", which seems completely wrong/misleading to me.

@BenVoigt it does not seem to have much to do with calle/caller-saved registers, as I can see different functions with a zero "Arguments" column using caller saved registers to spill arguments. Seems to only be related on stack space directly used by the caller for arguments, as Andrey suggested above.

@MarcoBonelli: .text is a section, not segment (within the pointer/address meaning).  Even in the context of ELF  That simply appears to be labelled wrong by IDA.

I have a question. According to MSDN, on x64, 4 registers are used for arguments and from the 5th argument onwards, the stack is used. However, your explanation mentions using 6 registers. Which one is correct?

@jeong: MSDN documents the Windows x86_64 calling convention, which isn't exactly the same as the SYS V one that the answer draws on (the "SYS V" mention was removed in one of the edits).

Oh, I was confused because I'm used to Windows. Thank you.

@BenVoigt
If so, is it difficult to estimate the value of the argument by only looking at the decompiled code? I use a 64-bit Windows system.

Example of a Decompiled Source

I would like to get the value of locals from the Function tab in IDA.

@jeong: The function signatures generated by IDA are pretty helpful toward that end (much more helpful than the "arguments" size would ever have been, even if correct).  However, IDA hasn't inferred pointers to structures, and your example decompilation includes what to me is clearly structure member access.  *a1 and a3 are both pointers to unknown structure types.

I think some of the functions you've shown are CRC calculations.

@BenVoigt ".text is a section, not segment" you are right, my bad, though it usually corresponds 1:1 to a RX section, so it's not rare to hear "text section". The confusion with IDA's naming and description of things is pretty wild :')
